# Canvas size is bigger than my image

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

Actually I want to work on custom view. And I created it successfully but one problem I am facing is canvas size. Lets say if my image size is 10 X 10 but my view (custom view) covering whole space.

Below my code :

```
public class StraightLine extends View {

    // private Bitmap mBitmap;

    private int rgbColorCode = 0xFFAD89F5;
    private int mWidth = 100;
    private int mHeight = 100;
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    Rect rect = new Rect();

    public StraightLine(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public StraightLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public StraightLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        rect.left = 0;
        rect.top = 0;
        rect.bottom = mHeight;
        rect.right = mWidth;
        mPaint.setColor(rgbColorCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, mPaint);
        // canvas.clipRect(rect);
    }

    /**
     * This method used to change the color of straight line. Color code should
     * be look like "0xFFAD89F5" last three digits are rgb color code
     * 
     * @param colorCode
     */
    protected void changeColor(int colorCode) {
        this.rgbColorCode = colorCode;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Now I am using this image in my xml as below:

```
<com.line.StraightLine
    android:id="@+id/straightLine1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Now canvas taking emapty sapce whatever it is.

Canvas size should be large as my image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `onMeasure` method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
}
```

This will indicate to your `View` its real width and height.

**Note**

The sizes used in your custom `View` are in pixels. Because of that, it won't be the same on every screen. To keep the same aspect on each device, you have to take in consideration the density of the screen when you draw this `View`.

Comment: I try below method and still i am not able to fix canvas size. Can you give some code snippets. Which have fix canvas size and object with in it have small size than canvas. Actually I want to know that which parameters affects canvas dimension and object also.